# how do you submit a support ticket to sendgrid if you can't login?

Tags: sendgrid

We cannot login because the 2fa never goes anywhere, but we can't submit a support ticket because support requires login.  what do we do?

If you click the have trouble logging in, you would think that one of these links would take you to a no-login support page (since you can't login, you can't login to submit a ticket):

I go here:

https://support.sendgrid.com/hc/en-us

I click this

[image]

I click this:

[image]

I get taken here:

[image]

UPDATE - The link does not work on firefox but works on chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SendGrid has a guide on how to contact support if you cannot log-in: https://docs.sendgrid.com/ui/account-and-settings/support#if-you-cannot-log-in

You can choose the “I am having a different login issue” to get to a form.

PS: If this doesn't work, try it with another browser.

Comment: you would think this would work but it doesn't i am updating the question to show why

Comment: Weird, I edited the answer. You should get to a from when you select "I am having a different login issue"

Comment: same, i am updating the question

Comment: Same? :-/ 
I end up at a form with the title "Please tell us more about your login issue!". Can you try to navigate there in a different browser or an incognito tab?

Comment: thanks for your follow up, turns out it is firefox, incognito on firefox doesn't work, but chrome does.

Comment: That's strange but at least it worked then. I added a comment in the original solution. Please go ahead and mark this question correct with the green checkmark if you found it useful.